# Using jQuery to handle checkboxes

Tags: jquery, forms, input

I am currently using a catch all method for all inputs on my form when it is being handled by jQuery.

```
$.each($(':input'),function()
{
    //stuff                 
});
```

What I need to be able to do is see if any of those inputs is a checkbox, at the moment the only thing I can find is to say if the field is checked or not.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just for your information: you have picked the wrong answer for two reasons
reason a: `:input` Matches all input, textarea, select and button elements. obviously, select are not needed in here. `input` would be more correct in this case.
reason b: the select all and then filter approach (input -> each -> if type == checkbox ) will cause unnecessary iterations, while `input[type=checkbox]` will filter them before the `.each` iteration comes into the picture.

Comment: Thanks for your concern, however selects are needed and I feel :input is the best way forward for the method as a whole.

Checkboxes need to be lumped in with everything else but I need something extra to happen when it is them.  The iterations will stay the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to know whether it's a checkbox inside that function:

```
$(':input').each(function() {
    if (this.type==='checkbox')
        ....
});
```

(Yeah, you can also say `$(this).attr('type')==='checkbox'` if you're one of those people who're dead set on using jQuery syntax for everything. But really, what's the point? It's only going to be slower and less readable.)

If you want to find only checkboxes, there's a special filter for that:

```
$(':checkbox').each(function() {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
   // stuff
});
```

Or even better

```
$('input:checkbox').each(function(){
   // stuff
})
```

see at http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/checkbox

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
$.each($(":input[type=checkbox]"), function() {
    // stuff
}
```

Comment: What's the point of doing `:input` here instead of just `input`?

Comment: :input is wrong. since it matches all `input`, `textarea`, `select` and `button` elements. and `select` are not needed at all in this case

Answer (score -1):

try this in `.each` function

```
if($('#myId').attr('type') == 'checkbox')
alert ('checkbox');
```

**UPDATE**

```
$.fn.tagName = function() {            
    return this.attr("type");          
}                                      
  $(document).ready(function() {       
    alert($('#testElement').tagName());
    });
```

Comment: checkbox is not a tagName, it's a type.